# PyQt QCalendarWidget -- method do not return value

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I have method getCurrentDate; this method must return the currently displayed month.

```
# coding: utf-8
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui


class Window(QtGui.QCalendarWidget):

    def __init__(self):

        QtGui.QCalendarWidget.__init__(self)

        self.resize(300, 300)
        self.connect(self, QtCore.SIGNAL('currentPageChanged()'), self.getCurrentDate)

        print self.getCurrentDate()

    def getCurrentDate(self):
        return self.monthShown()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    gui = Window()
    gui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

When i call getCurrentDate, it returns current value (e.g. 2 ), but when i change display to next month, method returns nothing. Why?

Comment: Just a side note: You should consider using the [new-style signal/slot support](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html) if you're using PyQt 4.5 or above.

Comment: Yes - if you'd used the new-style syntax and got the connection wrong, it would have raised a TypeError. The worst thing about the old-style syntax is that it fails silently (and it is very easy to get the SIGNAL signature wrong).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change this:

```
self.connect(self, QtCore.SIGNAL('currentPageChanged()'), self.getCurrentDate)
```

To:

```
self.connect(self, QtCore.SIGNAL('currentPageChanged(int,int)'), self.getCurrentDate)
```

This will return correct value and if you want to print the value then you need to put a print statement inside your function:

```
def getCurrentDate(self):
    print self.monthShown()
    return self.monthShown()
```

Comment: It's ok, but i passed value month from getCurrentDate to another method e.g. printCurrentDate, i get value only of current month.